# postgresql installation mac: Set the LC_ALL environment variable to a valid local

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to install postgresql 9.6 using brew on my mac and get the below error whenever i start the server :

`FATAL:  postmaster became multithreaded during startup
HINT:  Set the LC_ALL environment variable to a valid locale.
LOG:  database system is shut down`

The "locale" command gives the below output -

```
`LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
 LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
 LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
 LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
 LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
 LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
 LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
 LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"`
```

Can someone suggest where does postgresql picks LC_ALL and why is it unable to pick LC_ALL.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I solved it by updating my OS (macOS). The error had nothing to do with LC_ALL for me afterall.

```
Initial version: Sierra 10.12

Updated version: High Sierra 10.13
```

I think the OS update fixed it for me because it had to do with [this](https://github.com/PostgresApp/PostgresApp/issues/643).
Here is the link to find the high sierra update on the AppStore: [link](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/macos-high-sierra/id1246284741?mt=12)